# How to give image path in js/Jquery if image file exist in a different drive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My application is working in locale. I want to display one image using jquery. Image is located in one virtual drive created in my locale machine.

This is the path I given

```
var str='<div>';

str='<img src="'+virtualDriveName+':/test_folder/data/images/'+file_name+'.jpeg" height="100" width="100" >';
str+='</div>';

$(".ImageHolderDiv",$("#"+uniqueId)).append(str);
```

But its not displaying now. How to give image path if the needed image file exist in a different drive.

Eg:- My application running from C:drive. My image files are in F: drive. How can I display those images in my application?

Comment: where is set class ImageHolderDiv?

Comment: Sorry every thing is der. I cant post my whole code. If I give one image url (http://test.com/image1.jpeg) like that. It will work fine. My doubt is how to give one locale image path. That exist in a different drive.

Comment: Actually these code is using inside my custom plugin.

Comment: What is your environment system development? Win or Linux? If I can give you some advice, do not tie your code to external systems to your environment, or make sure you reach them via http! ;)

Comment: Hi I am using win. My application is a desktop application not web. So I create one virtual drive for mounting images. From there am reading my image files. So I give path like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit messy. Make sure, the image path is correct and try this:

```
var str = '<div>';
str += '<img src="'+virtualDriveName+':/test_folder/data/images/'+file_name+'.jpeg" height="100" width="100" />';
str += '</div>';
```

Try alerting `"'+virtualDriveName+':/test_folder/data/images/'+file_name+'.jpeg"` to check the path.

Also, try `...append($(str))`

Comment: Hi I alerted image path. Its comming correctly but not displaying. I am using windows machine.

Comment: Does the image show up using pure html <img.. /> and manually inserting the path? (I hope, you replace c: by your virtualDriveName)

Comment: Hi I can't give static values. Because my application is a desktop application not web. So I create one virtual drive for loading images. So I give path like that.

Comment: Just do it to check if the mistake is within the path or the javascript.